# SQL INTERSECT with most matched results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a question related to SQL script:

If I do this:

```
DECLARE @ProfileID int
SET @ProfileID = 1

SELECT [SetID],[ProfileID]
FROM [GeneralizedTable].[dbo].[DBProfileConditionTable]

where ([DBTypeID] = 4 AND ([ProfileID] = 1 OR [ProfileID] = 3 OR [ProfileID] = 13) AND [ConditionID] = 1 AND [CondMin] between 0 and 0 AND [CondMax] between 1000 and 1000)

group by [SetID], [ProfileID]

ORDER BY ABS([ProfileID] - @ProfileID)
```

this will sort the results that most matched with Profile = 1 on top.

But if I add some `INTERSECT` clauses to construct multiple search, will pop up a error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTERSECT'"

the final clause is :

```
DECLARE @ProfileID int
SET @ProfileID = 1

SELECT [SetID],[ProfileID]
FROM [GeneralizedTable].[dbo].[DBProfileConditionTable]

where ([DBTypeID] = 4 AND ([ProfileID] = 1 OR [ProfileID] = 3 OR [ProfileID] = 13) AND [ConditionID] = 1 AND [CondMin] between 0 and 0 AND [CondMax] between 1000 and 1000)

group by [SetID], [ProfileID]

ORDER BY ABS([ProfileID] - @ProfileID)

INTERSECT

SELECT [SetID], [ProfileID]
FROM [GeneralizedTable].[dbo].[DBProfileConditionTable]

where ([DBTypeID] = 4 AND ([ProfileID] = 1 OR [ProfileID] = 3 OR [ProfileID] = 13) AND [ConditionID] = 3 AND [CondMin] between 0 and 0 AND [CondMax] between 200 and 200)

group by [SetID], [ProfileID]

ORDER BY ABS([ProfileID] - @ProfileID)

INTERSECT
SELECT [SetID], [ProfileID]
FROM [GeneralizedTable].[dbo].[DBProfileParameterSetTable]

where ([DBTypeID] = 4 AND ([ProfileID] = 1 OR [ProfileID] = 3 OR [ProfileID] = 13) AND [BondClassificationID] = 0 AND [BondObjectID] = 0)

group by [SetID], [ProfileID]

ORDER BY ABS([ProfileID] - @ProfileID)
```

The running SQL Server is SQL Server 2005. Could you tell me which part is wrong to cause this error and how to solve

this to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: How could I use INTERSECT and ABS to sort the results with the most matched ones on top? Thank you.

Comment: You should remove all `order by` clauses, except the last one.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: I tried your method and it pop up another error:      "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: Unexpected; please see my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tad more complicated than I initially thought, but this should work (although I didn't test it...):

```
DECLARE @ProfileID int
SET @ProfileID = 1

SELECT  [SetID],[ProfileID]
FROM    (
SELECT [SetID],[ProfileID]
FROM [GeneralizedTable].[dbo].[DBProfileConditionTable]

where ([DBTypeID] = 4 AND ([ProfileID] = 1 OR [ProfileID] = 3 OR [ProfileID] = 13) AND [ConditionID] = 1 AND [CondMin] between 0 and 0 AND [CondMax] between 1000 and 1000)

group by [SetID], [ProfileID]


INTERSECT

SELECT [SetID], [ProfileID]
FROM [GeneralizedTable].[dbo].[DBProfileConditionTable]

where ([DBTypeID] = 4 AND ([ProfileID] = 1 OR [ProfileID] = 3 OR [ProfileID] = 13) AND [ConditionID] = 3 AND [CondMin] between 0 and 0 AND [CondMax] between 200 and 200)

group by [SetID], [ProfileID]


INTERSECT
SELECT [SetID], [ProfileID]
FROM [GeneralizedTable].[dbo].[DBProfileParameterSetTable]

where ([DBTypeID] = 4 AND ([ProfileID] = 1 OR [ProfileID] = 3 OR [ProfileID] = 13) AND [BondClassificationID] = 0 AND [BondObjectID] = 0)

group by [SetID], [ProfileID]
) a

ORDER BY ABS([ProfileID] - @ProfileID)
```

Comment: This will sort and order the results with most matched profile on top and others in the bottom